# Loading a libpeas module written in Vala and built with meson fails

Tags: shared-libraries, gnome, vala, meson-build, gnome-builder

I tried to build this example with the help of meson:
[Getting started with libpeas extensions in vala](http://steefhegeman.com/posts/2016/01/20/getting-started-with-libpeas-extensions-in-vala/)

My meson.build looks like the following:

```
vala_deps = [
  dependency('gio-2.0', version: '>= 2.50'),
  dependency('gtk+-3.0', version: '>= 3.22'),
]
libpeas_dep = dependency('libpeas-1.0')

libfoo_deps = [vala_deps, libpeas_dep]
libfoo = shared_library(
  'foo',
  'window.vala',
  vala_header: 'foo.h',
  dependencies: libfoo_deps,
  install: true,
)
libfoo_dep = declare_dependency(
      link_with: libfoo,
      dependencies: libfoo_deps,
      include_directories: include_directories('.'),
)

extension_deps = [vala_deps, libpeas_dep]
extension = shared_library(
  'extension',
  'extension.vala',
  vala_header: 'extension.h',
  dependencies: [vala_deps, libpeas_dep, libfoo_dep],
  install: true,
  #install_dir : '/app/bin'
)
extension_dep = declare_dependency(
      link_with: extension,
      dependencies: extension_deps,
      include_directories: include_directories('.'),
)

gnome = import('gnome')
extension_resources = gnome.compile_resources(    
  'extension-resources',                      
  'extension.gresource.xml',                      
  c_name: 'extension',                        
)
foo_sources = [
  'main.vala',
  extension_resources[0],
]
foo = executable(
  'foo',
  foo_sources,
  link_with: extension,
  #objects: 'libextension.so',
  dependencies: [vala_deps, libfoo_dep, extension_dep],
  install: true,
)
```

if I use the precompiled shared object file `objects: 'libextension.so',` inside `foo = executable(` the example works, if I don't it doesn't.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

the involved files have the following contents:

extension.gresource.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/org/gnome/Foo/plugins">
    <file>extension.plugin</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

extension.plugin:

```
[Plugin]
Name=extension
Module=extension
Embedded=peas_register_types
```

extension.vala:

```
class ValaExtension : Object, Foo.Extension {

    public Foo.Window window { get; construct set; }

    Gtk.Button button;

    void activate() {
        button = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Say Hello");
        button.clicked.connect(() => {
            button.set_label("Hello World!");
        });
        window.buttons.add(button);
        button.show();
    }

    void deactivate() {
        window.buttons.remove(button);
    }
}

[ModuleInit]
public void peas_register_types(TypeModule module) {
    var objmodule = module as Peas.ObjectModule;

    objmodule.register_extension_type(typeof (Foo.Extension), typeof (ValaExtension));
}
```

main.vala:

```
int main (string[] args) {
    var app = new Gtk.Application ("org.gnome.Foo", ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE);
    app.activate.connect (() => {
        var win = app.active_window;
        if (win == null) {
            win = new Foo.Window (app);
        }
        win.present ();
    });

    return app.run (args);
}
```

window.vala:

```
namespace Foo {

    public class Window : Gtk.Window {

        public Gtk.ButtonBox buttons { get; set; }

        private Peas.ExtensionSet extensions { get; set; }

        public Window(Gtk.Application app) {
            Object(application: app);

            this.buttons = new Gtk.ButtonBox(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL);
            this.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);

            var engine = Peas.Engine.get_default();

            engine.add_search_path("/app/lib", null);
            engine.prepend_search_path("resource:///org/gnome/Foo/plugins/", null);

            extensions = new Peas.ExtensionSet(engine, typeof (Foo.Extension), "window", this);
            extensions.extension_added.connect((info, extension) => {
                (extension as Foo.Extension).activate();
            });
            extensions.extension_removed.connect((info, extension) => {
                (extension as Foo.Extension).deactivate();
            });

            foreach (var plugin in engine.get_plugin_list())
                engine.try_load_plugin(plugin);

            this.add(buttons);
            this.show_all();
        }
    }

    public interface Extension : Object {
        public abstract Window window { get; construct set; }
        public abstract void activate();
        public abstract void deactivate();
    }
}
```

if I comment the `objects:'libextension.so'` line I get the following error:

```
(foo:2): libpeas-WARNING **: 20:27:31.400: Failed to get 'peas_register_types' for module 'extension': 'peas_register_types': foo: undefined symbol: peas_register_types

(foo:2): libpeas-WARNING **: 20:27:31.400: Error loading plugin 'extension'
```

**Solved:**

if I add a dummy function:

```
public void extension_init ()
{
}
```

to *extension.vala* and call it from *main.vala* the linking works properly for an *Embedded* plugin, see also here: [gnome_builder_plugins_init.c](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-builder/blob/60840c174b5015757801cfa194fea0552d7768ad/src/plugins/gnome-builder-plugins.c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objects: 'libextension.so'` would link the object directly in to the executable. From the example it looks as though you are loading a module at run time using libpeas. So by building the module in to the executable I would assume you are having trouble loading the module at runtime.

The tutorial also advises to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the directory with the extension and to also have a libpeas `.plugin` file. That could be the problem. It would help if you listed the error message or details of what is not working.

By the way to use an object from a meson build target it may be better to do `objects: extension.extract_objects()` so the name of the object is not hard coded in to the build. See [build target object](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#build-target-object). The use of `objects:` is mainly useful for tests though.

#### Update

I think your module name in `extension.plugin` should be `extension.so`. I also like to be explicit about the module loader so I've used `Loader=C` in the past. I've not come across `Embedded` before. So I would try this as my `extension.plugin`:

```
[Plugin]
Name=My first libpeas extension
Module=extension.so
Loader=C
```

Comment: Unfortunately setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` didn't solve it

Comment: `extension.extract_objects()` didn't work for me either, however removing the `Embedded` and installing the plugin file normally worked out. But I'm still wondering what the right setup for an `Embedded` plugin is. I came with the whole `Embedded` thing because I have seen it in the code of gnome-builder: [clang.plugin](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-builder/blob/5488fec495ac8320ea15384740130237f8225d23/src/plugins/clang/clang.plugin) and [meson.build](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-builder/blob/5488fec495ac8320ea15384740130237f8225d23/src/plugins/meson.build)

Comment: OK, in that case I would try adding `Builtin=true` to the `.plugin` file and maybe rename `peas_register_types` to a unique name for your embedded plugin, e.g. `my_extension_register_type`. Take a look at [https://developer.gnome.org/libpeas/stable/PeasPluginInfo.html#peas-plugin-info-is-builtin](https://developer.gnome.org/libpeas/stable/PeasPluginInfo.html#peas-plugin-info-is-builtin). There is also a [libpeas Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/libpeas/stable/index.html), but I can't find details of the `.plugin` file format there directly. Thanks for the info about `Embedded`